# Calling Get on MVC Controller Action Returning 404 Not Found in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, axios, asp.net-core-routing

I have an ASP.net core 2.0 MVC project and I'm calling some controller actions with axios to get a `JsonResult` of database items from the repository. This works when I'm running from visual studio but when I publish and then host on IIS, the axios call catches an error of 404 not found. The URL is correct. Even if I try the URL in postman I am given a 404 not found. URL is controller/action. What's weird is the `Index` action loads the view and does not give a 404. Only the axios call returns 404.

Only works when running from Visual Studio.

Below is the axios call

```
axios.get("Items/GetUnclaimedItems").then(function (response) {
        _this.items = response.data;
        _this.isBusy = false;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        alert("Error getting items. " + err);
    });
```

And the method within the controller.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetUnclaimedItems()
{
    Log.Information("Getting unclaimed items");
    var itemsList = new List<GikItemViewModel>();
    var itemsViewModel = new GikItemViewModel();
    var items = _repository.GetUnassignedItemsAsync();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        itemsList.Add(new GikItemViewModel
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Description = item.Description,
            CreateDate = item.CreateDate,
            Qty = item.Qty,
            Value = item.Value,
            Selected = false,
            Donation = item.Goods == 1 ? "Goods" : item.Services == 1 ? "Services" : "Facilities"
        });

    }
    return Json(itemsList);
}
```

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Person}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Comment: Show how you configure your routes. This looks like a routing issue.

Comment: Just using the standard default route of controller/action. Everything works when I run from Visual Studio but not after publishing. Does VS add some routing that we don't know about?

Comment: no. the path may be just relative when hosted locally but under a sub path when deployed. make sure you are calling the correct path

Comment: I've tried the path above shown in the `axios` call, `"Items/GetUnclaimedItems"` both without the `"/"` in front of items and with it. That path works. I would think that's the correct path and I use VS to publish so I don't change any folder structure around. In dev tools the path is `/Items/GetUnclaimedItems` as `/Items/Index` returns and loads the view page.

Comment: Include the controller and Index action in a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok I'll try. Here what's weird also. If I use the dotnet CLI and run `dotnet Gik_WebForm.dll` which is the main dll... Everything works. It's only when I host in IIS. And I've tried IIS on two different machines. One's IIS 8 and one's IIS 11. Both applications run but only the axios calls return not found, ajax, fetch... doesn't matter.

Comment: Show full startup.cs, program.cs.

Comment: Have you registered your repository in your startup.cs service?